Settings > Accessibility > Enable Animations : revert to yes by itself
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 from scratch (just keeping my previous home)
I disable animation in :
Settings > Accessibility > Enable Animations
Or in dconf-editor :
[org/gnome/desktop/interface]
enable-animations=true
But it revert to "enable" automatically
Thanks to help me to find a solution to keep disabled.
Thomas
